# Imposter syndrome when applying to international jobs?

Tags: job-search, career-development, work-experience

Its my first job as android developer and i have been working here for past eight months.
At work place i am usually on my own when creating apps, there are no mentors or senior developers above me, due to which imposter syndrome suffering comes into play.
Mostly i think about other companies with teams working in a project with expertise in a field so junior could learn from them.

There are alot of benefits in that, at my place i create apps and try to apply best practices on projects i am working on.

But still people with mentors with experience know things better and give you a better approach whether you are implementing oop, design patterns e.t.c.

The problem is when applying to international jobs mostly it says about working on big projects where as i have worked on small or average projects  so i still feel not ready for such jobs where as international jobs can give you much more experience.
I do have the capability if given such tasks so is it all right to apply with such little experience what will your advice be?

Comment: So, you're saying self-taught programmers are not good? That's not entirely true. Hint: It's a motivation for you.

Comment: Apply, and let them decide if your experience is good for them or if they'd prefer a different background. The main point is: apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Early in my career, I worked as the only web guy in a small shop.   Nothing made me grow in my skills like knowing if I didn't do it, it wouldn't get done.   There were days I was ready to bang my head on the keyboard in frustration...but I figured it out.   Keep plugging away...make use of online resources like message boards, blogs, and StackExchange.

In time if you go somewhere else to a bigger shop you'll be surprised how much you really do know.

Comment: Good answer. Supplement: Always google for best practices for what you are doing, read books, blogs, programming related subreddits, stack exchange sites, and participate in code review site specifically to get advice for your working code from experts.

Answer (score 0):

*How well you can learn* is much more important as a developer than *who is available for you to learn from*.

Having good mentors is a great advantage, but it's only a fraction of the advantage that you'll also have with a curious, open mind and the ability to teach yourself by using Google.

When you interview for more senior roles it won't matter how you've learned your skills, or who you learned them from. It will matter a lot that you **have** them, and can talk about them in an interview.